# invalidate - ios 6 does not stop the timer

Tags: ios, timer

I have a timer declared like so:

```
 @property (nonatomic,strong) NSTimer* tutorialTimer;
 ...
 self.tutorialTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 target:self selector:@selector(showTutorial) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

when clicking on a button I'm stopping the timer(or at least wish to stop) like so:

```
[self.tutorialTimer invalidate];
self.tutorialTimer = nil;
```

the timer keeps invoking...suggestions?

Comment: I bet you are reassigning it somewhere without invalidating it, thus "leaking" one.  Are you sure the `self.tutorialTimer` is not being called twice?  Does the timer get set in any other place in the class?

Comment: there is one function in which the timer gets set and initialized - called several times and every time the app "navigates"/opens a new srceen i stop the timer

Comment: before you initialize the timer, you should check.
if(!self.tutoialTimer) {
self.tutoxxx = xxx;
}

or if (self.timer) {[self.timer invalidate]};

self.timer = xxxx;

Answer (score 0):

NSTimer should work in  main Thread  . 
you can check the process use code

```
 if ([NSThread isMainThread])
{
   [self.tutorialTimer invalidate];
   self.tutorialTimer = nil;
}
```

to find out whether if it can step into  [self.tutorialTimer invalidate];